# What things to consider for - Indian Citizen on H1B visa in USA to take road trip to Canada?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, canada

I have Indian Passport with H1b visa. 
I want to take a road trip to Toronto and further east from Chicago. What are the things that I should consider while driving my own car.

- Will my Driver license from Illinois state will be valid in Canada?
- How will I pay tolls?
- Any other thing that I should consider?

Comment: Do you have a Canadian visa?

Answer (score 1):

Illinois driver's licenses are (like all US licenses) valid in Canada.  I'm not sure about tolls, but I don't remember there being any.  Take some Canadian dollars just to be safe.  If you don't spend them by the time you leave, go to the duty free shop on your way out.

Other things to consider: you will need a Canadian visa, as implied by [Jacob Horbulyk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/58919/jacob-horbulyk) in a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100679/what-things-to-consider-for-indian-citizen-on-h1b-visa-in-usa-to-take-road-tri#comment242035_100679).